# How do you access Gravity Form fields pre-submission?

Tags: forms, gravity

I'm trying to access the Gravity Forms fields pre-submission to check for gibberish entries. I've tried pretty much everything on StackOverflow and no luck.

The form is id #1. Some of the 1000 things I've tried include:

```
GFFormsModel::get_form_meta(1);
GFFormsModel::get_leads(1);
$_POST['input_1']
```

and reading this:
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_submission/

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fail silently for spam entries, I would recommend using the [gform_validation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_validation/) filter and, if you determine that the submission is spam, dynamically enable the honey pot. Gravity Forms will then fail the submission silently. The confirmation will be displayed but the entry will not be created.

Here's how my [GP Blacklist](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-blacklist/) plugin handles this:

```
$honeypot_field_id = GFFormDisplay::get_max_field_id( $form ) + 1;
$_POST[ "input_{$honeypot_field_id}" ] = true;
$form['enableHoneypot'] = true;
$result['is_valid'] = true;
```

**EDIT**

To actually retrieve the value, the simplest way is to just fetch it from the $_POST (FYI, there are more thorough techniques). Here's a more robust example.

```
add_filter( 'gform_validation', function( $result ) { 
    // Get the value of field ID 1
    $value = rgpost( 'input_1' );
    if( $value == 'gibberish' ) {
        // activate honeypot 
    }
    return $result;
} );
```

Comment: Thank you that sounds like a great exit strategy but how do I actually check the input fields in the first place? I have been unable to even get the entries that are input into the fields.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm, it still isn't working for me. $value ends up null. Should I change 'input_1' to be the field name or id or something?

Field 1 is the name so I'm just trying to output the name to see if it works.

`code`
$value = rgpost( 'input_1' );
die("Thank you $value !!");
`code`

I get: "Thank you !!" as my output though

Comment: Is the ID of your field 1?

Comment: Yes, it says "Field ID 1". I'm also using Form 1 if that matters. GF version is 2.3.5.

Comment: What type of field is it?

Comment: Name is name. And the company field that I'm also trying to get is a single line text field.

Comment: Try print_r on the $_POST so you can see what keys you need to fetch for the Name field.

Comment: I get: Array ( [input_1_3] => Bob [input_1_6] => Smith [input_2] => Bob's Company LLC [input_3] => bob@company.com